# Screen to Junos "Set route ...." command

Tags: routing, router, juniper-junos, screenos

tell me please how to translate the following Screenos  to Junos...
Do I understand correctly that the path to route 80.70.128.142/32 is via vrouter "UntrustGi-vr"  ?

*Screenos command:*

```
set vrouter "trust-vr"
set route 80.70.128.142/32 vrouter "UntrustGi-vr" preference 20 metric 1
```

*my Junos attempt:*

Maybe such interpretation in Junos???

```
set routing-instances trust-vr instance-type virtual-router

set routing-instances trust-vr routing options static route 80.70.128.142/32 next-table UntrustGi-vr.inet.0 preference 20 metric 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In screenos the command

```
set vrouter "trust-vr"
```

is moving you into editing the trust-vr router section. trust-vr is *normally* the default routing instance. The next command

```
set route 80.70.128.142/32 vrouter "UntrustGi-vr" preference 20 metric 1
```

adds an entry into the trust-vr routing table saying route all traffic to 80.70.128.142/32 to another virtual routing instance called "UntrustGi-vr" with a preference of 20 and metric 1

Now depending on if you have changed the trust-vr routing instance to be the non default would depend on how you would add it in Junos.

**If it is the default routing instance then you just need to do**

```
set routing-options static route 80.70.128.142/32 next-table UntrustGi-vr.net.0 preference 20
set routing-options static route 80.70.128.143/32 metric 1
```

which adds the static route into the default routing table inet.0. The config should look like this

```
routing-options {
    static {
        route 80.70.128.142/32 {
            next-table UntrustGi-vr.inet.0;
            metric 1;
            preference 20;
        }
    }
}
```

If you looked at the routing table you would see this

```
inet.0: 1 destinations, 1 routes (1 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

80.70.128.142/32   *[Static/20] 00:08:54, metric 1
                      to table UntrustGi-vr.inet.0
```

**If it isn't the default routing instance and you had created a routing instance called trust-vr then you would do**

```
set routing-instance trust-vr routing-options static route 80.70.128.142/32 next-table UntrustGi-vr.net.0 preference 20
set routing-instance trust-vr routing-options static route 80.70.128.142/32 metric 1
```

The config should look similar to this

```
routing-instances {
    trust-vr {
        routing-options {
            static {
                route 80.70.128.142/32 {
                    next-table UntrustGi-vr.inet.0;
                    metric 1;
                    preference 20;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the routing table should show this

```
trust-vr.inet.0: 1 destinations, 1 routes (1 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

80.70.128.142/32   *[Static/20] 00:03:15, metric 1
                      to table UntrustGi-vr.inet.0
```