# next-table may loop

Tags: juniper-junos, screenos

Help me to understand such situation. It is necessary translate a little of config from Screenos to Junos.

**Screenos issue:**

```
set vrouter "trust-vr"
set route 217.118.52.149/32 vrouter "TrustGi-vr" preference 20

set vrouter "TrustGi-vr"
set route 172.30.2.8/29 vrouter "trust-vr" preference 20
```

I would translate as here.
**Junos issue:**

```
set routing-instances trust-vr instance-type virtual-router
set routing-instances trust-vr routing-options static route 217.118.52.149/32 next-table TrustGi-vr.inet.0


set routing-instances TrustGi-vr instance-type virtual-router
set routing-instances TrustGi-vr routing-options static route 172.30.2.8/29 next-table trust-vr.inet.0
```

it seems that everything is logical and correct, but the error appears:

```
[edit routing-instances vrf-trust routing-options static]
root# commit check 
error: [rib vrf-trust.inet.0 routing-options static]
next-table may loop
error: configuration check-out failed
```

Chance of loops in screenos nobody cared. but in Junos felt that this possibility should be avoided.
Tell me how to translate this preferably using Policy-Statements ( not rib-groups).

Comment: Thank you for asking; I'm curious... is this question addressing the same problem as [this one](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6655/screen-to-junos-set-route-command)?

Comment: It's like a sequel...!Yet, Essentially two different questions! In the first case, I just wanted to know whether I translate the  configuration correctly??? But the problem with this issue is more complicated. I outlined it, I hope intelligibly!

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behaviour - see reference: http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB12985

Google junos auto-export for policy-based solutions

Comment: Please consider adding some details to this answers, so it won't be totally dependent on the contents of this link.